# How to make Subversion keep track of changes over a branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Let's say I have a task to do, that's gonna take some time to be accomplished. I wanna keep using config management advantages and of course don't wanna keep changes outside of Repo, but I also don't wanna commit the task until it's finished, in the same way I don't wanna be messed by changes made by other tasks that may affect mine. So, I decide to create a branch, work on it, use to for testing, and only merge back to trunk when changes are properly tested and have enough stability, then delete the branch.

So, how to properly branch and merge it? When I see a file log during branch work, I wanna be able to see changes made on it in trunk before the banch existed. And when I merge back to trunk, I wanna see changes made during branch work, as if it was done directly in trunk.

Any idea how to accomplish that with Subversion? I use Tortoise, but if needed I can use another client for branching and merging.

Did something change from Subversion 1.5 to 1.7 related to this behavior, that would make upgrading worth it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this can be accomplished.

Merging is covered by this section of the book:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html

1.7 has improvements to merge tracking so yes it would be helpful to upgrade:
http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#merge-tracking-enhancements